# Отправка записи на стену вконтакте (wall.post)

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

День добрый.

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как можно отправлять записи на стену вконтакте, маны по API вконтакте дают только параметры, мне же не ясна сама сущность. Насколько я понял, нужно использовать wall.post.

Нужно:

- давать пользователю возможность при клике на ссылку отправлять запись (которую я задам) на свою стену;
- иметь возможность мне выполнять свои задачи (занесение каких то данных через ajax в бд напр.)

Не нужно расписывать параметры, которые описаны [здесь](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.post), нужен простейший пример реализации. Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Язык то какой?

Comment: Если Вы про серверный, то php.

Comment: Я просто думал, там достаточно js для такого простого функционала..

Comment: Добавьте в теги лучше, а то   
> при клике на ссылку  

не очень заметно (может вы что-нибудь десктопное пишите).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разобрался, может кому надо будет

```
<div onclick="sendwallpost('Мой текст сообщения');">отправить</div>
<script language="javascript">
    VK.init({
        apiId: 11111111 // id созданного вами приложения вконтакте 
    });

    function sendwallpost(mydata) {
        VK.api("wall.post", {
            owner_id: '',
            message: mydata
        }, function (data) {});
    }
</script>
```